# How can I implement a regression test in bazel?

Tags: bazel

I have the following test target:

```
block_test (
    name = "full_test",
    block = ":block_name"
    ...
    params = {
        "PARAM1" : 1,
        "PARAM2" : 2,
        "PARAM3" : 3
    }
)
```

And I have a struct which defines the possible values of each param:

```
params_options = {
    "param1" : [1, 2, 34],
    "param2" : [43, 2 ,54],
    "param3" : [3, 5, 6]
}
```

I would like to have a single target that would run a target like `block_test` for every possible combination of parameters.

I thought about doing this by creating a macro which will declare a target for every possible combination of parameters, and finally a test target which will depend on those targets.

Is there any better approach? There may be thousands of combinations and so:

1. I'm afraid I'll get a big mess when querying the build.
2. I'm afraid that this isn't very performant, with regards to memory utilization.

Comment: I just found the [test_suite](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/general.html#test_suite) feature. This doesn't solve my issue of creating all of the tests without a macro,  but if this is my to go, it lets me group the tests and execute them under a single target.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a `block_test` for each set of parameters using list comprehension:

```
[block_test (
    name = "full_test",
    block = ":block_name"
    ...
    params = p
) for p in [
    {1, 2, 34},
    {43, 2 ,54},
    {3, 5, 6},
]]
```

Comment: Isn't this the same as using a macro? besides, the generated rules would have conflicting names, and I wouldn't end up with a single target which I could use to call all of the tests.
Both problems could be solved with a bit more complex Macro, but that kinda misses my question.